# Visual Studio solutions - correct location for utility EXEs needed by your solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, project-organization

Is there a proper place in a Visual Studio solution for .exes required by your solution. For example I'm working on a tool now that needs VHDCreate.exe, ISOCreate.exe, OSClone.exe and other exes. What is the right way to include them in a solution? I've inherited a solution where they are just stuck inside a folder inside the business layer project of the solution.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having a nicely organized tools folder at the level of the solution. Then you can use a solution folder to organize it separate from the rest of the projects.

Comment: Can that be incorporated into an installer easily? or does this only work well for XCopy type deployments?

Comment: oh i thought u were referring to builds... you really should have Merge Modules for your installs.

Comment: Make sure you mark them `Copy if newer` in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0):

This is with a native `.dll` but the concept is the same.

- Add existing item to solution and pick any folder where binaries exist:

[image: Add Existing]

- Select add as link from whatever folder outside solution you keep the binaries

[image: Add as Link]

- In the solution explorer set it as `Copy if newer`.

[image: Solution Explorer]

- The `.exe` or `.dll` will be copied to the build output folder if needed.

[image: Output Folder]

- When the original `.exe` gets updated the build will pull the newer one in the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read Mike Roberts series, *How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree*. The way Visual Studio does it by default is essentially broken, as far as I'm concerned.

- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Introduction](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/03/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-introduction/)
- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Part 1](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/04/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-part-1/)
- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Part 2](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/05/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-part-2/)
- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Part 3](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/06/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-part-3/)
- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Part 4](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/07/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-part-4/)
- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Part 5](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/08/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-part-5/)
- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Part 6](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/09/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-part-6/)
- [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree, Part 7](http://mikebroberts.com/2005/02/10/how-to-setup-a-net-development-tree-part-7/)

Single *.pdf: [How to Set Up a .Net Development Tree](http://mikebroberts.files.wordpress.com/2007/01/howtosetupadotnetdevelopmenttree.pdf)

Fundamentally, your directory structure should look like this:

- `Meta/Development Root`
  Usually mapped to root of source control system.

  - `Solution`
    One directory, contain your entire solution. Should be named to match the solution.

    - `Solution.sln`
      The solution file itself.
    - `nant.build`
      The nAnt build file for the solution.
    - `lib`
      The `lib` directory contains 3rd party assemblies/dlls that are referenced by the different projects in your solution. It is under source control. Project references should point here.
    - `tools`
      The `tools` directory contains all 3rd party tools required to build your solution. It, too, is under source control. The `tools` directory should contain the versions of `nAnt`, `nUnit` etc. used by your project — and your build scripts should reference these, rather than the version(s) installed on a developer's machine.
    - `bin`
      The `bin` directory contains the output of the build process for the solution. Each projects **must** be configured to point here.

      - `debug`
        debug build
      - `release`
        release build
    - `obj`
      In the ideal world, each project's `obj` would be pointed here as well as this has no place in the source tree. Sadly, Visual Studio doesn't offer an official way to do that (though, I'm told, VS can be hacked to do so if you're resourceful enough).
    - `src`
      The `src` directory is the root directory for the actual source code of your solution.

      - `project1`
        The directory for `project1`.

        - `project`.csproj`
          The project file.
        - `*.cs`, etc. files. The source files.
      - ...
      - `project-n`

How to structure individual projects is, I think, an entirely separate topic, but there should be, WRT to both the solution and the individual projects a correspondence between namespace and file system hierarchy. If a particular project requires a 3rd party assembly that is not to be available to other projects in the solution, an argument could be made for each such projects' directory to its own `lib` directory, but that scatters 3rd party assemblies across the source tree and so is not recommended.